# JUNG - Edges with icons

Tags: java, graph, jung, jung2

I am using JUNG for displaying network devices as graphs. Each edge is a link between two network elements. I want to add a picture exactly in the middle of the link.
Currently my link looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klBDN.png)

The code for it is:

```
vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new Function<GraphLink,String>() {
            URL url = getClass().getResource("/icons/model/conn.radio.png");
            public String apply(GraphLink input) {
                return "<html><img src="+url+" height=14 width=14>";
            }});
```

As you can see the icon is adjacent with the link. Is there any option so the link could split the icon in two equals parts?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** You want to tweak the edge label offset.

The position of the edge label is specified by a couple of properties, both accessible via the [RenderContext](http://jrtom.github.io/jung/javadoc/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/RenderContext.html):

- The EdgeLabelClosenessTransformer, which should return a value in the range [0, 1], specifies the position of the label along the edge, that is, whether it should be closer to the source node (0) or the target node (1).
- The edge label offset, which should return the distance from the edge to its label.

You can see how these properties are used (by default) in [BasicEdgeLabelRenderer](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/master/jung-visualization/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/renderers/BasicEdgeLabelRenderer.java).

By default, the edge label offset is set to 10, which should make the edge label fairly close to, but not on top of, the edge.  If you set it to 0:

`vv.getRenderContext().setLabelOffset(0);`

Then that should do what you want.

You may find it useful to experiment with [EdgeLabelDemo](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/master/jung-samples/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/EdgeLabelDemo.java).